# Android .designer.cs equivalent?

Tags: android

I've just coded android for a few months, and I really enjoy it, but I find myself writing the same "(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytextview)" code over and over again.

Coming from asp.net I can't help but wonder why there's no auto-generated class from which I can access my xml-declared views(controls) strongly typed?

Actually I kind of solved it for myself by creating a "viewshelper"-class for complex activities, so I can do "_views.mytextview" when I need the textview, but I still have to maintain these classes by hand each time I add or remove views.

Am I missing something, or should the android sdk do this for me?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look onto [roboguice](http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/), it looks like the library takes care about the problem.

Comment: Thank you, that looks nice, but you still have to manually declare and maintain your list of views, and a 100K lib for this seems a bit excessive...

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, You are missing the Java approach for application development.

This is quite normal for those that use Eclipse (with out plugins) at the beginning this seam to be very problematic, but now i think that that show only the developer limitation.